# why do some rankings depend on keywords grouped by "

Tags: seo, google, keywords

Say if i have a keyword "gold jewellery" this ranks my site on the first page of google. However typing: gold jewellery in google does not rank the site. What is the best way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Sorry but the question is far too board and Pro Webmasters has already dozens to hundreds of quality questions and answers regarding rankings and keywords. To avoid wasting your time please visit our help center in additional to using the search box in the top right hand corner.

Comment: Sorry, this may have been hasty but do you mean when using `" "`?